# Migrating from Heroku Redis toGo to Heroku Redis?

Tags: heroku, redis

Since the Heroku [redis-to-go](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/redistogo) addon being [shut down](https://redistogo.com/support) in August 2022, I'm wondering how to migrate my existing app on Heroku to use Heroku's own [Heroku Redis](https://www.heroku.com/redis) addon instead.
I am using a hobby tier with redis-to-go Nano at the moment.

Would the following two commands do the trick? (assuming no persistent data needs to be migrated)?

```
heroku addons:destroy redistogo
heroku addons:create heroku-redis:hobby-dev -a your-app-name
```

And then simply changing references in my code from `REDISTOGO_URL` to `REDIS_URL`?

Comment: I just did this. What you wrote works fine.

Comment: Exactly this, worked for me